# Invalid property value: API create Mutation Sanity.io Reference is string - how to define as reference?

Tags: properties, reference, sanity

i am building a ecommerce site.
I have trouble adding orderItems to the Array in the Order-Document.
As you can see i am trying to reference the customer-Document and Product-Dokument in my orderItem. i am Posting in an array of objects that looks like:

```
[
  {
    productId: '5b79b3f8-6ef8-4c6d-bd85-5dcb14fb836d',
    kundenId: 'c3777230-74cd-411b-a455-7fa905c90957',
    quant: 1,
    name: 'Position 1'
  }
]
```

**Can someone help me how i get sanity to understand the strings as _ref ?**

My schemas are as follows:

```
export default {
  title: 'Order Item',
  name: 'orderItem',
  type: 'object',
  fields: [
    {
      title: 'Name',
      name: 'name',
      type: 'string',
    },
    {
      name: 'kundenId',
      title: 'Customer',
      type: 'reference',
      to: [{ type: 'customer' }],
      options: {
        disableNew: true,
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'productId',
      title: 'Product',
      type: 'reference',
      to: [{ type: 'product' }],
      options: {
        disableNew: true,
      },
    },
    {
      title: 'Quantity',
      name: 'quant',
      type: 'number',
    },
    {
      title: 'Price',
      name: 'price',
      type: 'number',
    },
  ],
};
```

and:

```
export default {
  name: 'order',
  title: 'Order',
  type: 'document',
  fields: [
    {
      name: 'user',
      title: 'User',
      type: 'reference',
      to: [{ type: 'user' }],
      options: {
        disableNew: true,
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'userName',
      title: 'User Name',
      type: 'string',
    },
    {
      title: 'Order Items',
      name: 'orderItems',
      type: 'array',
      of: [
        {
          title: 'Order Item',
          type: 'orderItem',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      title: 'CreatedAt',
      name: 'createdAt',
      type: 'datetime',
    },
  ],
};
```

[image: screenshot of error in sanity.io]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i solved this by using JSON.parse like so:

```
productId: JSON.parse(`{"_ref":"${artikel._id}"}`),
```

Good luck to everyone with the same issue.

Comment: also good to know : for the missing _key error one can use "npm nanoid" https://www.sanity.io/answers/can-i-import-some-utility-for-generate-keys-p1605541489245000